# Looking for a way to change the fixed height of page header in Access 2007

Tags: height, ms-access-2007, sectionheader

I am new at modifying reports in Access and would sincerely appreciate any help to find a away to change the height of a page header in Access 2007.

I have a page header stuck with a height of 22". I try to move the page header up using the double arrow and tried entering in a new height in the properties box but the height remains the same.

I have browsed online and I see that other individuals have had the same issue and the work around was to delete a 'line control', unfortunately I can't find a line to delete and I can't seem to fix this issue. Any help would be amazing. (If the solution is to fix the line control, is it possible for someone to provide a detailed guide on how to do this? I understand it could be generic but I just can't seem to figure it out on my own :) )

Thank you!!

Comment: I added a solution with the step-by-step I was looking for- thanks

Comment: Could you direct me to your solution?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have some control, like a line in the report header, in wich case you need to delete it or move it above.

Kind regards
Emilio

Answer (score 0):

1) When in draft view, right click in page header section
2) Select properties
3) Under EVENT tab, click ... on any option
4) If asked, use code builder
5) vba will open
6) Under properties window, use the drop down and find all the lines
7) Change the line property TOP to 0 if the property shows a negative
8) Save and exit vba
9) You can now change the height in Access
10) Save

Comment: What is "draft" view?  Very confusing.  What exactly are you doing here?